# React Component Logging in with Authorization Code Grant and Amplify/Cognito hosted UI

Tags: oauth-2.0, react-hooks, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm successfully using the Cognito federated sign in with the hosted ui in my react app.  This login flow redirects to a login url in my application. My intent is to fetch the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() in a **useEffect** hook when the auth_code appears on the request (for now just looking to see if the search component has any value) and then to redirect to another route.

The problem I'm having is that the ***https://foo-api.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token*** call that Amplify makes behind the scenes doesn't return until after the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser promise resolves with a failure.

My naive workaround/solution was to wrap that call in a timer, see below. This works fine, but seems brittle and wrong-headed (even if I handle the possibility of infinite calls).

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {useLocation, useHistory} from "react-router-dom"
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
import { CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider } from "@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/types";


const App = () => {

  useAuthentication();

  function useAuthentication() {
    const location = useLocation()
    const history = useHistory()
    useEffect(_ => {
      if(location.search) {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
          .then(_=> history.push('/'))
          .catch(console.log)
        }, 1000)
        return _ => clearInterval(interval)
      }
    }, [location]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() =>
          Auth.federatedSignIn({
            provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Cognito
          })
        }
      >
        Federated sign in
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This seems almost like an Amplify bug, at least when I'm trying to use it like this. I see that this issue comes up here: [AWS Cognito hosted UI and Amplify Auth with authorization code OAuth flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444242/aws-cognito-hosted-ui-and-amplify-auth-with-authorization-code-oauth-flow). But I'm not using any other Amplify components like Hub.

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to handle this situation?

Comment: why not to use Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser after the Auth.federatedSignIn is finished in the .then().

Comment: That would be superb!  But Auth.federatedSignIn.then() always resolves without any credentials.  And then the browser navigates away to an auth url.

Comment: like the docs here! https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/advanced/q/platform/js